# Thread returns error in android 4.0.3 version

Tags: android

I have a question that I have a splash screen in my android app in which I am using thread to wait for 8 seconds, it is running fine in 1.6,2.1,2.2,2.3.3, 3.0, 3.1 but returns error when I want to run the same in 4.0.3 version of android, I don't know why? Please suggest me the right solution for the same. Below I mentioned error stack and my code also.

**Error Stack:**

```
01-05 10:16:06.417: E/AndroidRuntime(589): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-75
01-05 10:16:06.417: E/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
01-05 10:16:06.417: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1076)
01-05 10:16:06.417: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1063)
01-05 10:16:06.417: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.shipface.common.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:34)
```

**Code:**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Thread splash;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        splash =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {

                    synchronized(this){
                    // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(4000);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
                }

                finish();


                stop();                    
            }
        };


        splash.start();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everybody's already said where the exception is coming from (`Thread.stop()`), so I'll leave that alone...

By far, the easiest method is to not create a `Thread` for this purpose at all; even an `AsyncTask` is over-doing it.  This is what the `Handler` was created for (or even `CountDownTimer`, but `Handler` is cleaner, IMO).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable action = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(action, 8000);  
}
```

The `Handler` will even run the action on the main thread for you, where that code should pretty much be called anyway.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Thread.stop is deprecated method which is the reason you are getting exception. It will work on lower versions with a warning. Try using AsyncTask instead of threads. They are much safer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to `stop()` the Thread, `stop()` is already deprecated it you want to stop the Thread you can use `thread_instance.interrupt()`. But, simply this will do,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [stop](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29)() method is Deprecated.
In earlier versions, `UnsupportedOperationException` was just ignored, you can see it in the log though. But in 4.0.3, it is considered as Fatal exception.
You can remove the call to stop() in your code. It is unnecessary.